# Does java object retain hashcode value when transmitted over the network

Tags: java, serialization, hashcode

If I have a serializable java object where hashcode method is not over ridden, and then i transmit the java object over the netwrok and on the receiving end, reconstruct the java object, then will the hashcode method return the same value ?

Is it something specified by the Java API or implementation dependent based on the JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, as others have said if you are depending on transient fields then the value of the hashcode will be different, but it also depends on how your hashcode is implemented.  If your hashcode method depends on the hashcode of objects that either use transient objects or the default method(or itself depends on objects that use those) then the hashcode may very well end up different.

Although not specified by the standards, the default hashcode for objects usually just returns their internal address, and this will obviously be different depending on which machine the jvm is running on..... Overall I would not depend on any hashcode method that you do not control returning the same thing after being serialized/deserialized

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in the Java Language Specification, Java Virtual Machine Specification, or Object Serialization Specification that says so. So you can't rely on it, whatever behaviour you may happen to observe in any particular case.

Comment: +1 Especially since the OP wrote that the method is not overwritten, which then means we take java.lang.Object's hashCode() function which relies on memory adress which most probably will be different on a different machine.

Comment: @Matthias It *may* rely on memory address. It may not. It may do anything at all. It isn't specified.

Answer (score 0):

During serialization some fieds may be not seriazlied, eg transient fields. In this case the hashcode of the serialized object will differ from the original one.

Answer (score 0):

We will get difference in hashCode between deserilized object and original object in all situation if we are depending on Object class hashCode method.. You can test it by serailizing any user object to a file..